# random variables not independent but $\mathrm{E}[X|Y]=\mathrm{E}[X]$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I have to find two r.v. X,Y defined in a probability space ($\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathrm{P}$), which are not independent but for which  $\mathrm{E}[X|Y]=\mathrm{E}[X]$ nonetheless, with $X\in\mathrm{L^1}(P)$.

Suggestions?

Comment: Do y ou mean $E[X\mid Y] = E[X]$?

Comment: corrected, sorry

Comment: Please also edit the title, and I would avoid using abbreviations when not needed, too.

Comment: Let $Y,Z$ be two independent normally distributed r.v. and let $X=YZ$?

Comment: then I would have $Y\mathrm{E}[Z]$, and not $\mathrm{E}[YZ]$...(and why normal?)

Comment: @VittorioApicella The answer you accepted is a version of Hagen's suggestion.

Comment: yes, I noticed after watching Liu's answer, I didn't see at a first look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y$ be uniform random variable on $(0,1)$ and conditionally on $Y$, $X$ is a centered normal random variable with variance equal to $Y$.

Then $E(X|Y) = E(X) = 0$, but $X$ is not independent of $Y$ since $E(X^2 | Y) = Y$

$E(X^2) = E(Y) = \frac{1}{2}$ implies $X \in L^1$